# How do I enable /SAFESEH with assemly-code / SEH-performance

Tags: windows, winapi, assembly, x86

I've developed a little program that tests the performance of 32 bit Windows structured exception handling. To keep the overhead minimal in contrast to the rest, I wrote the code generating an filtering the exception in assembly.

This is the C++-code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool __fastcall getPointerFaultSafe( void *volatile *from, void **to );

int main()
{
    auto getThreadTimes = []( LONGLONG &kt, LONGLONG &ut )
    {
        union
        {
            FILETIME ft;
            LONGLONG ll;
        } creationTime, exitTime, kernelTime, userTime;
        GetThreadTimes( GetCurrentThread(), &creationTime.ft, &exitTime.ft, &kernelTime.ft, &userTime.ft );
        kt = kernelTime.ll;
        ut = userTime.ll;
    };
    LONGLONG ktStart, utStart;
    getThreadTimes( ktStart, utStart );
    size_t const  COUNT = 100'000;
    void         *pv;
    for( size_t c = COUNT; c; --c )
        getPointerFaultSafe( nullptr, &pv );
    LONGLONG ktEnd, utEnd;
    getThreadTimes( ktEnd, utEnd );
    double ktNsPerException = (ktEnd - ktStart) * 100.0 / COUNT,
           utNsPerException = (utEnd - utStart) * 100.0 / COUNT;
    cout << "kernel-time per exception: " << ktNsPerException << "ns" << endl;
    cout << "user-time per exception:   " << utNsPerException << "ns" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the assembly-code:

```
.686P
PUBLIC ?getPointerFaultSafe@@YI_NPCRAXPAPAX@Z
PUBLIC sehHandler
.SAFESEH sehHandler
sehHandler PROTO

_DATA SEGMENT
byebyeOffset dd 0
_DATA ENDS

exc_ctx_eax = 0b0h
exc_ctx_eip = 0b8h

_TEXT    SEGMENT

?getPointerFaultSafe@@YI_NPCRAXPAPAX@Z PROC
ASSUME ds:_DATA
    push    OFFSET sehHandler
    push    dword ptr fs:0
    mov     dword ptr fs:0, esp
    mov     byebyeOffset, OFFSET byebye - OFFSET mightfail
    mov     al, 1
mightfail:
    mov     ecx, dword ptr [ecx]
    mov     dword ptr [edx], ecx
byebye:
    mov     edx, dword ptr [esp]
    mov     dword ptr fs:0, edx
    add     esp, 8
    ret     0
?getPointerFaultSafe@@YI_NPCRAXPAPAX@Z ENDP

sehHandler PROC
    mov     eax, dword ptr [esp + 12]
    mov     dword ptr [eax + exc_ctx_eax], 0
    mov     edx, byebyeOffset
    add     [eax + exc_ctx_eip], edx
    mov     eax, 0
    ret     0
sehHandler ENDP


_TEXT    ENDS
END
```

1. How do I get the asm-module of my program /SAFESEH-compatible?
2. Why does this program consume so much userland CPU-time? The library-code being called by the operating-system after the exception has begun to be handled should have only to save all the registers in the CONTEXT-structure, fill the EXCEPTION_RECORD-structure, call the topmost exception-filter which - in this case - shifts the execution two instructions further, and when it returns it will in my case restore all the registers an continue execution according to what I returned in EAX. That's should all not be so much time that almost 1/3 of the CPU-time will be spent in userland. That's about 2,3ms, i.e. when my old Ryzen 1800X is boosting on one core with 4GHz, about 5.200 clock-cycles.
3. I'm using the byebyeOffset-variable in my code to carry the distance between the unsafe instruction that might generate an access-violation and the safe code afterwards. I'm initializing this variable before the unsafe instruction. But it would be nice to have this offset statically as an immediate at the point where I add it on EIP in the exception-filter function sehHandler; but the offsets are scoped to getPointerFaultSafe. Of course storing the offset and fetching it from the variable take a negligible part of the overall computation time, but it would be nicer to have a clean solution.

Comment: For 3) there's nothing stopping you from doing `mov [eax + exc_ctx_eip], OFFSET byebye`.  There's no need to perform an addition.

Comment: @RossRidge: No, the labels are local to the function. I get an undefined symbol error from what you suggest.

Comment: Change `byebye:` to `byebye::` to make it global.

Comment: Hi, did you solve the issue? if so, could you please share the solution and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/643302) yourself?